# how to fire an event when custom dialog is dismissed?

Tags: android, dialog

I am creating my own custom dialog box .And i want to trigger an event when custom dialog box is dismissed but not able to do so .

Note : there is no option for Ondismiss()  is coming -so i can overwrite it .
       here is my code:

```
 Dialog pdialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

         pdialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            pdialog.setContentView(R.layout.cust);

            ImageView cancel=(ImageView) pdialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
            TextView txtheader=(TextView) pdialog.findViewById(R.id.txttheader);

            txtheader.setText("Accent Report");





        pdialog.show();


    pdialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.out.println("hello world@@@@@");// this line is not getting called.

        }
    });



        pdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        pdialog.setCancelable(true);

    }
```

Comment: Have you already tried all the things suggested in the answers below? Have you tried tracing the flow with a debugger to find out which methods are called when the dialog gets closed?

Comment: dialog is getting closed on setOnClickListener

Comment: if i use setondismisslistner -on dismiss is not getting called.

Comment: And does the dialog close any other way? I see in the code you block other means of closing the dialog.

Comment: yup , i modified my code and set my setcancelable  to true,so if i touch outside dialog is getting dismissed but  setondismisslistner -on dismiss is not getting called

Comment: Aah. Maybe you want to update the question to reflect that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70034/discussion-between-abh22ishek-and-jegesh).

Answer (score 0):

In your custom dialog's class definition, override the dismiss() function and perform your action in that. Something like below:

```
@Override
public void dismiss() {
 someListener.onActionHappened(); //your action
 super.dismiss();
}
```

Try overriding the cancel method as well. I haven't tested this one.

```
@Override
public void cancel() {
 someListener.onActionHappened(); //your action
 super.cancel();
}
```

Comment: on dismiss is not getting called() if i press cancel button on my dialog box

Answer (score 0):

simple ans sweet .. you can add action in your OnClickListener ... it will dismiss your dialog  as well as perform action

```
cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
pdialog.dismiss();  
// Your Action Here

    }
});
```

Comment: it will not getcalled if user pressed on backpressed or ontouchoutside

Comment: then set cancel dialog false and also perform action on backpress

Answer (score 0):

what action you are taking to dismissing your custom dialog,
by pressing cancel button of custom dialog or on pressing back button of device?
you can try below code 
where View is your custom dialog view

```
 View view=View.inflate(context, R.layout.activity_account_history_screen, null);
    if(view.isShown()) 
    {
    //do some task
    }
    else`enter code here`
    {}
```

Comment: i have a cancel button . in which i am calling setonclicklistner- and also with      setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)

Comment: then you are actually getting the event in which dialog will dismiss 
you can fire an event on 
setonclicklistner on dialogs cancel button and for dismissing dialog while touching outside there is 2 options 
1. make setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
another put on touchlistener on base layout and in setontouchlistener
check dialog view is visibe or not via code